# ld: archive member '/' not a mach-o file

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

I am using clang++ to to compile and got the following error:

```
ld: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/user/Documents/accountable-robust-mpc-code/SimpleOT/libsimpleot.a'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This was the command that gave me an error:

```
clang++ -o mascot-party.x -march=native -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libsodium/include -I/usr/local/opt/mpir/include -I/usr/local/opt/boost/include -I/usr/local/opt/gmp/include -g -Wextra -Wall -O3 -I. -pthread   -DMAX_MOD_SZ=5 -DUSE_GF2N_LONG '-DPREP_DIR="Player-Data/"'  -std=c++17 -fopenmp -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -fPIC Machines/mascot-party.o OT/OTTripleSetup.o OT/BaseOT.o SimpleOT/libsimpleot.a libSPDZ.so Machines/SPDZ.o OT/BitDiagonal.o OT/MascotParams.o OT/OTExtension.o OT/OTExtensionWithMatrix.o -lmpirxx -lmpir -lsodium -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libsodium/lib -L/usr/local/opt/mpir/lib -L/usr/local/opt/boost/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gmp/lib -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Users/user/Documents/accountable-robust-mpc-code
```

I am working on a Macbook Pro with an Intel i5 processor running macOS Sonoma 14.2.1.

Here is my CONFIG file:

```
ROOT = .

OPTIM= -O3
#PROF = -pg
#DEBUG = -DDEBUG
GDEBUG = -g

# set this to your preferred local storage directory
PREP_DIR = '-DPREP_DIR="Player-Data/"'

# set for SHE preprocessing (SPDZ and Overdrive)
USE_NTL = 0

# set for using GF(2^128)
# unset for GF(2^40)
USE_GF2N_LONG = 1

# set to -march=<architecture> for optimization
# SSE4.2 is required homomorphic encryption in GF(2^n) when compiling with clang
# AES-NI and PCLMUL are not required
# AVX is required for oblivious transfer (OT)
# AVX2 support (Haswell or later) is used to optimize OT
# AVX/AVX2 is required for replicated binary secret sharing
# BMI2 is used to optimize multiplication modulo a prime
# ADX is used to optimize big integer additions
# delete the second line to compile for a platform that supports everything
ARCH = -mtune=native -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -maes -mpclmul -mavx -mavx2 -mbmi2 -madx
ARCH = -march=native

MACHINE := $(shell uname -m)
OS := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(MACHINE), x86_64)
# set this to 0 to avoid using AVX for OT
ifeq ($(OS), Linux)
CHECK_AVX := $(shell grep -q avx /proc/cpuinfo; echo $$?)
ifeq ($(CHECK_AVX), 0)
AVX_OT = 1
else
AVX_OT = 0
endif
else
AVX_OT = 1
endif
else
AVX_OT = 0
endif

# allow to set compiler in CONFIG.mine
CXX = g++

# MAX_MOD_SZ (for FHE) must be least and GFP_MOD_SZ (for computation)
# must be exactly ceil(len(p)/len(word)) for the relevant prime p
# GFP_MOD_SZ only needs to be set for primes of bit length more that 256.
# Default for MAX_MOD_SZ is 10, which suffices for all Overdrive protocols
MOD = -DMAX_MOD_SZ=5

# use CONFIG.mine to overwrite DIR settings
-include CONFIG.mine

ifeq ($(USE_GF2N_LONG),1)
GF2N_LONG = -DUSE_GF2N_LONG
endif

ifeq ($(AVX_OT), 0)
CFLAGS += -DNO_AVX_OT
endif

LDLIBS = -lmpirxx -lmpir -lsodium $(MY_LDLIBS)
LDLIBS += -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto

ifeq ($(USE_NTL),1)
CFLAGS += -DUSE_NTL
LDLIBS := -lntl $(LDLIBS)
endif

ifeq ($(OS), Linux)
LDLIBS += -lrt
endif

ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
BOOST = -lboost_thread-mt $(MY_BOOST)
else
BOOST = -lboost_thread $(MY_BOOST)
endif

CFLAGS += $(ARCH) $(MY_CFLAGS) $(GDEBUG) -Wextra -Wall $(OPTIM) -I$(ROOT) -pthread $(PROF) $(DEBUG) $(MOD) $(GF2N_LONG) $(PREP_DIR) $(SECURE) -std=c++17 -fopenmp
CPPFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
LD = $(CXX)

ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
# for boost with OpenSSL 3
CFLAGS += -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations
ifeq ($(USE_NTL),1)
CFLAGS += -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=deprecated-copy
endif
endif
```

and my Makefile:

```
include CONFIG

MATH = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Math/*.cpp))

TOOLS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Tools/*.cpp))

NETWORK = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Networking/*.cpp))

PROCESSOR = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Processor/*.cpp))

FHEOBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard FHEOffline/*.cpp FHE/*.cpp)) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o

GC = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard GC/*.cpp)) $(PROCESSOR)
GC_SEMI = GC/SemiSecret.o GC/SemiPrep.o GC/square64.o

OT = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard OT/*.cpp))
OT_EXE = ot.x ot-offline.x

COMMONOBJS = $(MATH) $(TOOLS) $(NETWORK) GC/square64.o Processor/OnlineOptions.o Processor/BaseMachine.o Processor/DataPositions.o Processor/ThreadQueues.o Processor/ThreadQueue.o
COMPLETE = $(COMMON) $(PROCESSOR) $(FHEOFFLINE) $(TINYOTOFFLINE) $(GC) $(OT)
YAO = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Yao/*.cpp)) $(OT) BMR/Key.o
BMR = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard BMR/*.cpp BMR/network/*.cpp))
MINI_OT = OT/OTTripleSetup.o OT/BaseOT.o $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
VMOBJS = $(PROCESSOR) $(COMMONOBJS) GC/square64.o GC/Instruction.o OT/OTTripleSetup.o OT/BaseOT.o $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
VM = $(MINI_OT) $(SHAREDLIB)
COMMON = $(SHAREDLIB)


LIB = libSPDZ.a
SHAREDLIB = libSPDZ.so
FHEOFFLINE = libFHE.so
LIBRELEASE = librelease.a

ifeq ($(AVX_OT), 0)
VM += ECDSA/P256Element.o
OT += ECDSA/P256Element.o
MINI_OT += ECDSA/P256Element.o
else
LIBSIMPLEOT = SimpleOT/libsimpleot.a
endif

# used for dependency generation
OBJS = $(BMR) $(FHEOBJS) $(TINYOTOFFLINE) $(YAO) $(COMPLETE) $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Machines/*.cpp Utils/*.cpp))
DEPS := $(wildcard */*.d */*/*.d)

# never delete
.SECONDARY: $(OBJS) $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard */*.cpp))


all: arithmetic binary gen_input online offline externalIO bmr ecdsa
vm: arithmetic binary

.PHONY: doc
doc:
    cd doc; $(MAKE) html

arithmetic: rep-ring rep-field shamir semi2k-party.x semi-party.x mascot sy
binary: rep-bin yao semi-bin-party.x tinier-party.x tiny-party.x ccd-party.x malicious-ccd-party.x real-bmr

all: overdrive she-offline
arithmetic: hemi-party.x soho-party.x gear

-include $(DEPS)
include $(wildcard *.d static/*.d)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c

online: Fake-Offline.x Server.x Player-Online.x Check-Offline.x emulate.x

offline: $(OT_EXE) Check-Offline.x mascot-offline.x cowgear-offline.x mal-shamir-offline.x

gen_input: gen_input_f2n.x gen_input_fp.x

externalIO: bankers-bonus-client.x

bmr: bmr-program-party.x bmr-program-tparty.x

real-bmr: $(patsubst Machines/%.cpp,%.x,$(wildcard Machines/*-bmr-party.cpp))

yao: yao-party.x

she-offline: Check-Offline.x spdz2-offline.x

overdrive: simple-offline.x pairwise-offline.x cnc-offline.x gear
gear: cowgear-party.x chaigear-party.x lowgear-party.x highgear-party.x

rep-field: malicious-rep-field-party.x replicated-field-party.x ps-rep-field-party.x

rep-ring: replicated-ring-party.x brain-party.x malicious-rep-ring-party.x ps-rep-ring-party.x rep4-ring-party.x

rep-bin: replicated-bin-party.x malicious-rep-bin-party.x ps-rep-bin-party.x Fake-Offline.x

replicated: rep-field rep-ring rep-bin

spdz2k: spdz2k-party.x ot-offline.x Check-Offline-Z2k.x galois-degree.x Fake-Offline.x
mascot: mascot-party.x spdz2k mama-party.x

ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
tldr: mac-setup
else
tldr: mpir linux-machine-setup
endif

tldr:
    $(MAKE) mascot-party.x

ifeq ($(MACHINE), aarch64)
tldr: simde/simde
endif

shamir: shamir-party.x malicious-shamir-party.x atlas-party.x galois-degree.x

sy: sy-rep-field-party.x sy-rep-ring-party.x sy-shamir-party.x

ecdsa: $(patsubst ECDSA/%.cpp,%.x,$(wildcard ECDSA/*-ecdsa-party.cpp)) Fake-ECDSA.x
ecdsa-static: static-dir $(patsubst ECDSA/%.cpp,static/%.x,$(wildcard ECDSA/*-ecdsa-party.cpp))

$(LIBRELEASE): Protocols/MalRepRingOptions.o $(PROCESSOR) $(COMMONOBJS) $(OT) $(GC)
    $(AR) -csr $@ $^

CFLAGS += -fPIC
LDLIBS += -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(CURDIR)

$(SHAREDLIB): $(PROCESSOR) $(COMMONOBJS) GC/square64.o GC/Instruction.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

$(FHEOFFLINE): $(FHEOBJS) $(SHAREDLIB)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

static/%.x: Machines/%.o $(LIBRELEASE) $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -Wl,-Map=$<.map -Wl,-Bstatic -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++  $(LIBRELEASE) $(LIBSIMPLEOT) $(BOOST) $(LDLIBS) -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl

static/%.x: ECDSA/%.o ECDSA/P256Element.o $(VMOBJS) $(OT) $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -Wl,-Map=$<.map -Wl,-Bstatic -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ $(BOOST) $(LDLIBS) -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl

static-dir:
    @ mkdir static 2> /dev/null; true

static-release: static-dir $(patsubst Machines/%.cpp, static/%.x, $(wildcard Machines/*-party.cpp)) static/emulate.x

Fake-ECDSA.x: ECDSA/Fake-ECDSA.cpp ECDSA/P256Element.o $(COMMON) Processor/PrepBase.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

ot.x: $(OT) $(COMMON) Machines/OText_main.o Machines/OTMachine.o $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

ot-offline.x: $(OT) $(LIBSIMPLEOT) Machines/TripleMachine.o

gc-emulate.x: $(VM) GC/FakeSecret.o GC/square64.o

bmr-%.x: $(BMR) $(VM) Machines/bmr-%.cpp $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(BOOST) $(LDLIBS)

%-bmr-party.x: Machines/%-bmr-party.o $(BMR) $(SHAREDLIB) $(MINI_OT)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(BOOST) $(LDLIBS)

bmr-clean:
    -rm BMR/*.o BMR/*/*.o GC/*.o

bankers-bonus-client.x: ExternalIO/bankers-bonus-client.cpp $(COMMON)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

simple-offline.x: $(FHEOFFLINE)
pairwise-offline.x: $(FHEOFFLINE)
cnc-offline.x: $(FHEOFFLINE)
spdz2-offline.x: $(FHEOFFLINE)

yao-party.x: $(YAO)
static/yao-party.x: $(YAO)

yao-clean:
    -rm Yao/*.o

galois-degree.x: Utils/galois-degree.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

default-prime-length.x: Utils/default-prime-length.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

secure.x: Utils/secure.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^

Fake-Offline.x: Utils/Fake-Offline.o $(VM)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.x: Utils/%.o $(COMMON)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.x: Machines/%.o $(MINI_OT) $(SHAREDLIB)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

%-ecdsa-party.x: ECDSA/%-ecdsa-party.o ECDSA/P256Element.o $(VM)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)

replicated-bin-party.x: GC/square64.o
replicated-ring-party.x: GC/square64.o
replicated-field-party.x: GC/square64.o
brain-party.x: GC/square64.o
malicious-rep-bin-party.x: GC/square64.o
ps-rep-bin-party.x: GC/PostSacriBin.o
semi-bin-party.x: $(OT) GC/SemiSecret.o GC/SemiPrep.o GC/square64.o
tiny-party.x: $(OT)
tinier-party.x: $(OT)
spdz2k-party.x: $(OT) $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Machines/SPDZ2*.cpp))
static/spdz2k-party.x: $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard Machines/SPDZ2*.cpp))
semi-party.x: $(OT) GC/SemiSecret.o GC/SemiPrep.o GC/square64.o
semi2k-party.x: $(OT) GC/SemiSecret.o GC/SemiPrep.o GC/square64.o
hemi-party.x: $(FHEOFFLINE) $(GC_SEMI) $(OT)
soho-party.x: $(FHEOFFLINE) $(GC_SEMI) $(OT)
cowgear-party.x: $(FHEOFFLINE) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o $(OT)
chaigear-party.x: $(FHEOFFLINE) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o $(OT)
lowgear-party.x: $(FHEOFFLINE) $(OT) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o Protocols/LowGearKeyGen.o
highgear-party.x: $(FHEOFFLINE) $(OT) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o Protocols/HighGearKeyGen.o
atlas-party.x: GC/AtlasSecret.o
static/hemi-party.x: $(FHEOBJS)
static/soho-party.x: $(FHEOBJS)
static/cowgear-party.x: $(FHEOBJS)
static/chaigear-party.x: $(FHEOBJS)
static/lowgear-party.x: $(FHEOBJS) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o Protocols/LowGearKeyGen.o
static/highgear-party.x: $(FHEOBJS) Protocols/CowGearOptions.o Protocols/HighGearKeyGen.o
mascot-party.x: Machines/SPDZ.o $(OT)
static/mascot-party.x: Machines/SPDZ.o
Player-Online.x: Machines/SPDZ.o $(OT)
Accountable-Player.x: Machines/SPDZ.o $(OT) $(FHEOBJS)
Accountable-%.x: $(COMMONOBJS) $(FHEOBJS) Machines/Accountable-%.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)
mama-party.x: $(OT)
ps-rep-ring-party.x: Protocols/MalRepRingOptions.o
malicious-rep-ring-party.x: Protocols/MalRepRingOptions.o
sy-rep-ring-party.x: Protocols/MalRepRingOptions.o
rep4-ring-party.x: GC/Rep4Secret.o
no-party.x: Protocols/ShareInterface.o
semi-ecdsa-party.x: $(OT) $(LIBSIMPLEOT) GC/SemiPrep.o GC/SemiSecret.o
mascot-ecdsa-party.x: $(OT) $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
fake-spdz-ecdsa-party.x: $(OT) $(LIBSIMPLEOT)
emulate.x: GC/FakeSecret.o
semi-bmr-party.x: GC/SemiPrep.o GC/SemiSecret.o $(OT)
real-bmr-party.x: $(OT)
paper-example.x: $(VM) $(OT) $(FHEOFFLINE)
mascot-offline.x: $(VM) $(OT)
cowgear-offline.x: $(OT) $(FHEOFFLINE)
static/rep-bmr-party.x: $(BMR)
static/mal-rep-bmr-party.x: $(BMR)
static/shamir-bmr-party.x: $(BMR)
static/mal-shamir-bmr-party.x: $(BMR)
static/semi-bmr-party.x: $(BMR)
static/real-bmr-party.x: $(BMR)
static/bmr-program-party.x: $(BMR)
static/no-party.x: Protocols/ShareInterface.o

ifeq ($(AVX_OT), 1)
$(LIBSIMPLEOT): SimpleOT/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -C SimpleOT

OT/BaseOT.o: SimpleOT/Makefile

SimpleOT/Makefile:
    git submodule update --init SimpleOT
endif

.PHONY: Programs/Circuits
Programs/Circuits:
    git submodule update --init Programs/Circuits

.PHONY: mpir-setup mpir-global mpir
mpir-setup:
    git submodule update --init mpir
    cd mpir; \
    autoreconf -i; \
    autoreconf -i
    - $(MAKE) -C mpir clean

mpir-global: mpir-setup
    cd mpir; \
    ./configure --enable-cxx;
    $(MAKE) -C mpir
    sudo $(MAKE) -C mpir install

mpir: mpir-setup
    cd mpir; \
    ./configure --enable-cxx --prefix=$(CURDIR)/local
    $(MAKE) -C mpir install
    -echo MY_CFLAGS += -I./local/include >> CONFIG.mine
    -echo MY_LDLIBS += -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(CURDIR)/local/lib -L$(CURDIR)/local/lib >> CONFIG.mine

mac-setup: mac-machine-setup
    brew install openssl boost libsodium mpir yasm ntl
    -echo MY_CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libsodium/include  -I/usr/local/opt/mpir/include -I/usr/local/opt/boost/include -I/usr/local/opt/gmp/include >> CONFIG.mine
    -echo MY_LDLIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libsodium/lib -L/usr/local/opt/mpir/lib -L/usr/local/opt/boost/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gmp/lib >> CONFIG.mine
#   -echo USE_NTL = 1 >> CONFIG.mine

ifeq ($(MACHINE), aarch64)
mac-machine-setup:
    -echo ARCH = >> CONFIG.mine
linux-machine-setup:
    -echo ARCH = -march=armv8.2-a+crypto >> CONFIG.mine
else
mac-machine-setup:
linux-machine-setup:
endif

simde/simde:
    git submodule update --init simde

accountable: 
    ./build-benchmarks.sh

accountable-online:
    ./build-online-benchmarks.sh

accountable-offline:
    ./build-offline-benchmarks.sh

online-with-docker:
    sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz -w /workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz accountable-robust-mp-spdz sh build-online-benchmarks.sh

offline-with-docker:
    sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz -w /workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz accountable-robust-mp-spdz sh build-offline-benchmarks.sh

with-docker:
    sudo docker build -t accountable-robust-mp-spdz - < Dockerfile
    sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz -w /workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz accountable-robust-mp-spdz rm -f *.x
    sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz -w /workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz accountable-robust-mp-spdz make clean 
    sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz -w /workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz accountable-robust-mp-spdz make -j 8 mpir
    sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz -w /workspaces/accountable-mp-spdz accountable-robust-mp-spdz make accountable

clean:
    -rm -f */*.o *.o */*.d *.d core.* *.a gmon.out */*/*.o static/*.x *.so
```

I am using the version of clang installed using homebrew rather than the default Xcode clang. Any help with this error would be much appreciated.